# Web host for serving both western and asian users

Tags: hosting, cdn, china

Are there any hosting companies specialized in serving both European, N+S American and Chinese, Indian, Korean or Japanese users?

I am looking for a dedicated or VPS to host a Drupal site, not a CDN.

Thanks.

Comment: In what way do you want this "specialised" host to differ from any other? Why is a "normal" host not suitable?

Comment: Good peering with the different sides of the globe. A 'normal' host with good to great performance in the US or Europe does not necessarily work well with China and Apac countries.

Answer (score 3):

So you want one service provider with one instance, equidistant from North and South America, Europe, and Asia.

I would recommend hosting at the Earth's core. Then you'll pick up Africa, Australia, and Antarctica for no additional charge.

Seriously, though, you can't beat the laws of physics. Whenever you host in one place, people farther away will have a worse experience than people close. That's why Akamai can charge so damned much. Because they provide better service than people who don't.

You need more than one host, or you need to host your service "in the cloud" with a provider who will distribute your app for you. Or you need to accept the fact that people who go undersea or over satellite to get to your stuff will have a slower experience. It's physics.

Comment: +1 just for mentioning that there is something in the Southern hemisphere and that we also use the Internet.

Comment: I'd be happy with 3 or 4 out of the many regions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out www.infrenion.com which serving both western and asian users, fantastic support quality at affordable dedicated and VPS plans. I'm fully satisfied and being with then for last 18 months.

Honestly I feel nice to have such hosting provider.

Comment: I did have a look, but can't find any info about them being particularly suited to visitors in Asia.